# How i convert type datetime-local to string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Asp.net core MVC 3.1 ,
I need to edit my code. I searched a lot but nothing found which solves my issue.
First I have a column type "datetime"
  the data is like this "2020-01-01 14:22:00.000" in SqlServer.

When upload these values to input, I am getting the following error

> "Input string was not in a correct format."

Following is my index.cshtml code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label asp-for="shift_to" class="control-label"></label>
  <input class="shift_to" asp-for="shift_to" type="datetime-local"   />
  <span asp-validation-for="shift_to" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function calculate() {
  var  startTime = $('.shift_from')[0].value;
  var endTime    = $('.shift_to')[0].value;
  return (new Date(endTime) - new Date(startTime)) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
}

$('.shift_to').change(function () {
  $('.shift_hours').val(calculate());
});
```

Comment: where specifically do you get the error message? on the back-end? In SQL?

Comment: When i load the page the error appear :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The `FORMAT()` function also allows you to [format date and time](https://database.guide/how-to-format-the-date-time-in-sql-server/) in SQL Server.

For example;

```
FORMAT(Created, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm') AS DateCreated 
--08.24.2019 14:24
```

If you need to format date in JavaScript:

```
const date = new Date(2019, 0, 23, 17, 23, 42)

toString // Wed Jan 23 2019 17:23:42 
toDateString // Wed Jan 23 2019
toLocaleString // 23/01/2019, 17:23:42
toLocaleDateString // 23/01/2019
toGMTString // Wed, 23 Jan 2019 09:23:42 GMT
toUTCString // Wed, 23 Jan 2019 09:23:42 GMT
toISOString // 2019-01-23T09:23:42.079Z
```

Comment: Where can i put this line in javascript ?

Comment: I changed to :  type="datetime-local" value="2020-01-01 14:22:00.000"  the same error